# javascript trigger 'click' after a period of inactivity then stop if active

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, setinterval

I'm quite stumped by a problem where I would like an animation that I have which is triggered by the next click function to automatically occur if there is a period of inactivity of say about 30 seconds - I'd be using the mousemove or hover states to determine this - then finally stop the inactivity trigger if there is activity. I guess I'd have use setInterval/timeout but all my previous attempts continued to trigger the click despite the 30second rule.

I have a fiddle with full code to demonstrate here : http://jsfiddle.net/83rBU/

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you inquiring about a clearTimeout ? http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Check fixed code on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/83rBU/9/)

P.S. Sorry old link was wrong

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you, couldnt get my head around the set/clear timeouts properly! Thanks very much!!

Comment: I updated the code as this still ran if there was interaction with the page or not, on the fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/83rBU/13/ essentialy I use an 'idleTime' variable which increments every five seconds if no 'mouseenter' , 'keypress' or 'click' events.